# How do I reduce my resolution without resorting to scaling my screen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display-resolution

I want to reduce my resolution to 1280x720 because my monitor displays at 3200x1800. I'm using the Nvidia drivers and don't seem to be getting that option here. Using the Xorg drivers gets me the results I want, but it makes my laptop extremely slow. Is it possible to change the display resolution without using the Nvidia X Server Settings app to shrink the view rect?

Nvidia Card: Quadro K2100M

Ubuntu version: 22.0.4.1

Comment: Can you please add to your question the version of Ubuntu that you're using? This will help in resolving your issue. Thanks

Comment: @richbl Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: You don't have the option in your system settings?

Comment: The only option I have is 3200x1800